# How to disconnect from all database connection strings

Tags: perl, database-connection, dbi, disconnect

I have a Perl script which connects to many databases using different connection drivers.

Is there any way I can write a single disconnect function in the end to disconnect if there are any active session?

Example :

```
connection 1: $dbh->oracle;
connection 2: $dbh->sql
```

Can I have a common disconnect string for both databases?

Comment: DBI will disconnect implicitly for you when the statement handle goes out of scope.

Comment: @simbabque : i am getting error as: Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect().....i am using separate disconnect function to prevent this , but it would be great to use a single disconnect function for all the strings .

Answer (score 5):

You can implement that yourself using [`visit_handles` from DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#visit_handles).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh  = DBI->connect( 'DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost', 'root', 'pw' );
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect( 'DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost', 'root', 'pw' );

DBI->visit_handles(
    sub {
        my ( $driver_handle, $info ) = @_;

        if ($driver_handle->{Type} eq 'db') {
            # clean up transaction or simply disconnect for each handle
            $driver_handle->disconnect;
        }

        return 1;
    }
);
```

The code reference passed to `visit_handles` will be called for each driver handle. If it returns a true value, it will subsequently call [`visit_child_handles`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#visit_child_handles) with the same code reference. That way, you can match which ones are database handles (`db`) and disconnect them explicitly.

As [Borodin states in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38699216/1331451) you need to take care of the half-done transactions before disconnecting. This solution only gives you a means to get all the connection handles from a single place.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `visit_handles`. But calling `disconnect` on everything explicitly will produce the same warning as the implicit disconnects done when perl destroys a program, and you need to `rollback` or `commit` on every handle that has an open transaction.

Comment: @borodin hmm true. I'll edit when I get back to my computer.

Comment: @Borodin i was unaware of this , thanks for the information . i am trying to connect with different drivers like oracle,postgres and mysql. Just skeptical about whether this will work or not , will try when i get back to my computer

Answer (score 2):

Each database connection will be represented as a separate database handle `$dbh`

Clearly you could write a subroutine that disconnects from all connected database handles, as long as your list of connected databases is always the same

I'm not sure why you're fixating on the connection strings. Presumably you mean  the DSNs (Data Source Names) that you used in the call to `DBI->connect`? They are simply parameters to the connection operation and a database handle cannot be identified after the fact from its original DSN

> ```
> Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect()
> ```

This implies that you are using transactions. The best way would be to call `rollback` or `commit` yourself to end the transaction. It's a bad idea to leave a transaction open when the program terminates as you are relying on the default behaviour of the database driver

The [documentation for `DBI::disconnect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#disconnect) says this

> Generally, if you want your changes to be committed or rolled back when you disconnect, then you should explicitly call "commit" or "rollback" before disconnecting.

You will also get the same warning if you call `disconnect` while a transaction is still open, so a `commit` or `rollback` is definitely the correct method

It is fine to let Perl's destruction sequence implcitly disconnect all database handles as long as no transactions are left open at the time